Work required to pump water from an underground cistern to ground level
A rectangular cistern has its top $10$ ft. below ground level. Its dimensions are $20$ ft. long x $12$ ft. wide, and $10$ ft. high. It is filled with water; therefore, its volume is $12 \times 20 \times h$. The water weighs $62.4$ lb/cubic ft. How much work is required to pump the water to ground level?
The force required to lift the water is $62.4 \times 20 \times 12 \times h = 14976h$. The distance is $(h + 10)$. The required integral, therefore, is: $$14976 \int_{-20}^{-10} h(h+10) dh $$Solving the integral $14976 \times 2500/3$ = $12480000$ ft-lb.
The textbook answer is $2246400$ ft-lb, which seems to ignore that the top of the cistern is $10$ ft. below ground level. Which is correct? Thanks

Please format your formulas.

Their answer is what I also get. They are not ignoring the location. Their integral is $$-14976\int_{-20}^{-10}h : dh$$ because at each level $h\in[-20,-10]$ the work needed to pump a thin rectangle of water at that level (and with thickness $dh$) is $-(14976 : dh)h$, where minus sign just appears since $h$ is negative in this frame of reference.

See my answer here. The center of mass of the cistern is $z = -\left( d + \frac{1}{2} h \right)$ relative to the ground, where $d = 10 \text{ ft}$ is the depth of the top surface and $h = 10 \text{ ft}$ is the height of the cistern. Its mass is $m = \rho V = \rho l w h$, where $\rho = 62.4 \frac{\text{lbm}}{\text{ft}^3}$ is the density of water and $l = 20 \text{ ft}$ is the length and $w = 12 \text{ ft}$ is the width of the cistern. With $g = 1 \frac{\text{lbf}}{\text{lbm}}$, we have that the change in gravitational potential in bringing all the water to ground level, which must be supplied by external work, is
$$\Delta U = - m g z = \rho g l w h \left( d + \frac{1}{2} h \right)$$
Plugging in the parameter values, we get
$$\Delta U = \left( 62.4 \frac{\text{lbm}}{\text{ft}^3} \right) \left( 1 \frac{\text{lbf}}{\text{lbm}} \right) (20 \text{ ft}) (12 \text{ ft}) (10 \text{ ft}) \left( 10 \text{ ft} + \frac{1}{2} (10 \text{ ft}) \right)$$
$$= \boxed{2.25 \times 10^6 \text{ ft-lbf}}$$
which matches the textbook's answer.
